# Change colors already set through out the app in flutter dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, colors, sharedpreferences

I have a **colors.dart** file in my app project where i assign a color to a variable and use through out my whole app but the problem is that i can't seem to change it if i want to

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var errorRed = Color(0xFFE84118).withOpacity(0.9);
var successC = Color(0xff62d770);
var primary = Color(0xFFCC002F);
var nBlack = Colors.black87;
var green = Colors.green;
var white = Colors.white;
var grey = Colors.grey;
var red = Colors.red;
```

and in my app i just set a color like **color: primary,** but now i want my user to be able to change the colors as they want. I have tried using shared preference to store hex colors value and later convert to color but it didn't work

```
Color hexToColor(String value) {
   String coloV = gShared(value);
   return Color(int.parse(coloV.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
 }

sShared(String key, String value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await prefs.setString(key, value);
}

Future<String> gShared(String key) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString(key);
}


///So i saved the color like
await sShared("U_PRI", "0xFF00CC2F");

///and then tried setting it to the variable
var primary = hexToColor(gShared("U_PRI)) ?? Color(0xFFCC002F); // didn't work at all
```

Please is there a better way to manage my colors so it can be used throughout the whole app because if i try to change the color using themeData some parts won't change because i have already assigned a color to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change to a color object that widgets are relying on you need to make sure that the other widgets are also rebuilt. I don't know if this solution is to large of a scale but a good solution for changing the theme of your app would be to make a "Theme Manager" above you app. This theme manager would basically just rebuild the app using whatever theme you want set.
Something like this

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeManager();
  }
}

class ThemeManager extends StatefulWidget {
  ThemeManager({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ThemeManagerState createState() => _ThemeManagerState();

  static _ThemeManagerState? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<_ThemeManagerState>();
  }
}

class _ThemeManagerState extends State<ThemeManager> {
  ThemeData _theme = ThemeData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: _theme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Menu(),
    );
  }

  void changeTheme(ThemeData newTheme) {
    _theme = newTheme;
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

when you want to change theme you call

```
ThemeManager.of(context).changeTheme(newTheme);
```

Side note: If you don't care to change the whole theme or you just don't want to use the theme for some reason. You can just store your colors in the state and create a change color function instead that calls setState